# dynamically call a control

Tags: c#, winforms

Let's say I have 30 controls, all lbls, all called "lblA" with a number after.

I also have 30 textboxes, same thing - called "txtB" with a number after.

How exactly would I formated this.

```
for (i = 1; i < this.controls.count;i++)
{
    if ("lblA"+i=null)
    {
        break;
    }
    string A = string A + ("lblA" + i).Text
    string B = string B + ("txtB" + i).Text
}
```

I've tried a few different things like calling the object with this.controls[i] but it's not exactly what I want. What I am doing is I have a lot of labels and text boxes in a form that are added at run time. I need to loop through the form to get them all. I'm writting it as a for each with quite a few ifs, but I'm curious if there's a dynamic way to do it.

I've looked for about 1-1:30 hours online and found nothing close to, thanks for the help all.

Comment: Is this question about ASP.NET?

Comment: This is simply a windows form C# program.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var labels = new Dictionary<int, string>();
for (i = 1; i < this.controls.count;i++)
{
    var label = FindControl("lblA" + i) as Label;
    if (label == null)
    {
        break;
    }
    labels.Add(i, label.Text);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you want to use is the FindControl method.

Example in VB:

```
 Dim txtMileage As TextBox = CType(cphLeft.FindControl("txtMileage" & iControlCountDays.ToString()), TextBox)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this will solve what you're after:

```
void GetSpecialControls() {
  const string TXT_B = "txtB";
  const string LBL_A = "lblA";
  List<TextBox> textBoxList = new List<TextBox>();
  List<Label> labelList = new List<Label>();
  foreach (Control ctrl in this.Controls) {
    Label lbl = ctrl as Label;
    if (lbl != null) {
      if (lbl.Text.IndexOf(LBL_A) == 0) {
        labelList.Add(lbl);
      }
    } else {
      TextBox txt = ctrl as TextBox;
      if (txt != null) {
        if (txt.Text.IndexOf(TXT_B) == 0) {
          textBoxList.Add(txt);
        }
      }
    }
  }
  Console.WriteLine("Found {0} TextBox Controls.", textBoxList.Count);
  Console.WriteLine("Found {0} Label Controls.", labelList.Count);
}
```